# How to straighten my Scindapsus Aureum (moss stick)

Tags: houseplants, containers

The moss stick of my Scindapsus Aureum of about 180 cm has gone crooked. I tried to fix it by placing another stick beside it, but that doesn't seem to help (for long).

How can I fix this so the moss stick will keep straight and not lean over?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe a larger pot will help it stabilize?

Comment: @b.nota indeed repotting to a larger container and pressing/tightening the soil around the moss-stick seems to solve the problem, thanks. If you can post this as an answer I'll be glad to accept. :-)

Comment: You are right, if it answers your question, I can post it as answer. Which is also good for the site statistics!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a larger pot will help to stabilize it? With a larger pot the stick will have more volume and mass to hold on to.

Comment: Thanks, seems so obvious now, but at the moment of asking the question, it wasn't. :-)